# How to use docker-compose instead of Dockerfile during deploy to Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, deployment, continuous-integration

Right now I'm deploy my apps to Heroku with using `Dockerfile`. This command below using only this file and ignore `docker-compose`:

```
heroku container:login
heroku container:push web -a ${{ secrets.HEROKU_APP_NAME }}
heroku container:release web -a ${{ secrets.HEROKU_APP_NAME }}
```

can someone tell me how to deploy container to heroku container registry but with using docker-compose? I need to use docker-compose because I've many images in one container like eq. redis.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "I've many images in one container like eq. redis"—you can't run your own Redis (or other supporting service) container on Heroku. See Beppe C's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku does not support docker-compose, but only recommends using it for [local development](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose).
Once your development/testing is done you push the application and use Heroku add-ons for redis, etc..

> The python application depends on Postgres and Redis, which you do not push to Heroku. Instead, use Heroku add-ons in production.